# Weird behaviour when intersecting polygons in python Shapely

Tags: python, intersection, shapely, isochrone

I'm using shapely to get the intersection between an isochrone polygon and a restriction area my car can't leave. I have a list of restriction areas, some of which overlaps by little, making it harder to use MultyPolygon. If I use a unary union to get a layer of restrictions, in the intersection appears a lot of little holes, even though every individual polygon of the layer is a polygon without inner holes. Like this isochrone polygons:

[image: Isochrone polygon]

Becomes this:

[image: Isochrone intersection restriction layer]

If I intersect the isochrone against each individual polygon, It return from this restriction polygon:

[image: restriction isochrone intersection]

I get this:

[image]

Which also seems odd, as my restriction polygons are usually way larger than my isochrones.

Am I making some misuse of shapely? Where did I go wrong?
I'd really love to do the union against a restriction layer, as it seems more robust, but can't get around the little holes problem. The restriction layer have some polygons really far away, some are  in differenty countries

The code Im using, in a colab notebook, is this:
For intersection against restriction layer:

```
restriction = unary_union(polygons)
d['House'].intersection(restriction)
```

For intersection against each restriction polygon:

```
for i in range(len(polygons)):
    if polygons[i].contains(d['House']):
        print(d['House'])
    elif  d['House'].intersects(polygons[i]) == True:
           print(d['House'].intersection(polygons[i]))
```

The polygon is this:

```
POLYGON ((-3.722322 40.477412, -3.720397 40.47437, -3.71477 40.469595, -3.714273 40.469134, -3.711822 40.467529, -3.707334 40.456688, -3.70868 40.455463, -3.708862 40.455304, -3.711995 40.450507, -3.713945 40.447921, -3.714084 40.446001, -3.713086 40.444425, -3.709765 40.440505, -3.708445 40.438757, -3.702465 40.429471, -3.696448 40.423029, -3.694301 40.420546, -3.692291 40.418017, -3.689524 40.41623, -3.689118 40.416215, -3.67892 40.410545, -3.682851 40.400448, -3.685517 40.399057, -3.69287 40.392118, -3.697285 40.391343, -3.699814 40.388781, -3.694429 40.379795, -3.691468 40.377748, -3.689047 40.379118, -3.686508 40.38167, -3.682859 40.384749, -3.673361 40.386913, -3.670412 40.386854, -3.670387 40.386882, -3.664393 40.392469, -3.664371 40.392507, -3.662908 40.395354, -3.652773 40.399805, -3.651398 40.399261, -3.648593 40.397397, -3.645454 40.394152, -3.644214 40.392604, -3.642087 40.391315, -3.641956 40.391257, -3.641916 40.391239, -3.633618 40.390018, -3.630025 40.390238, -3.621394 40.3888, -3.61803 40.388035, -3.617107 40.391515, -3.617703 40.391673, -3.620621 40.392316, -3.628335 40.393714, -3.628543 40.393828, -3.629081 40.393919, -3.638862 40.395147, -3.639609 40.395298, -3.644459 40.405902, -3.644216 40.406587, -3.635748 40.412911, -3.631213 40.411619, -3.628057 40.409886, -3.625359 40.408368, -3.622189 40.406661, -3.621372 40.407584, -3.620138 40.408666, -3.609687 40.411048, -3.6084 40.410769, -3.607443 40.410588, -3.606773 40.414125, -3.60773 40.414306, -3.608922 40.414566, -3.616004 40.417763, -3.623218 40.422649, -3.617337 40.431899, -3.607608 40.433999, -3.607434 40.433953, -3.599743 40.427448, -3.596346 40.426255, -3.596329 40.426304, -3.592123 40.435654, -3.582467 40.438151, -3.580638 40.438587, -3.576332 40.447988, -3.573004 40.447914, -3.572923 40.451513, -3.576251 40.451587, -3.579579 40.451662, -3.581633 40.451424, -3.583749 40.451429, -3.588941 40.451029, -3.59553 40.457471, -3.596308 40.460123, -3.594161 40.466973, -3.584279 40.466437, -3.582835 40.464956, -3.579279 40.465516, -3.579362 40.466044, -3.579458 40.46648, -3.582127 40.469336, -3.583146 40.469998, -3.586605 40.46856, -3.595262 40.470614, -3.599445 40.475753, -3.603044 40.475853, -3.610701 40.47366, -3.616005 40.477976, -3.618656 40.47833, -3.61876 40.478304, -3.619605 40.477953, -3.630228 40.48047, -3.631768 40.481872, -3.636163 40.485813, -3.633707 40.496727, -3.629291 40.496355, -3.625362 40.496908, -3.621844 40.496895, -3.620968 40.49693, -3.621112 40.500527, -3.621988 40.500492, -3.626891 40.500381, -3.635777 40.501008, -3.639684 40.500725, -3.647728 40.507825, -3.647993 40.516162, -3.643543 40.522535, -3.643408 40.522676, -3.641192 40.525645, -3.636751 40.529096, -3.62786 40.529805, -3.622522 40.529873, -3.61977 40.530181, -3.618363 40.530431, -3.615198 40.532008, -3.61417 40.532555, -3.613479 40.532968, -3.615327 40.536057, -3.623095 40.533427, -3.627629 40.533398, -3.637325 40.537045, -3.6408 40.538516, -3.644214 40.540241, -3.646357 40.540804, -3.647272 40.537322, -3.652692 40.52725, -3.652671 40.524561, -3.652965 40.522663, -3.655536 40.517544, -3.665776 40.514752, -3.668847 40.517249, -3.672612 40.519321, -3.683139 40.521937, -3.683732 40.522032, -3.685699 40.521959, -3.687598 40.521398, -3.691433 40.520074, -3.694849 40.517623, -3.696986 40.516015, -3.701461 40.505995, -3.707824 40.499088, -3.707868 40.496543, -3.711466 40.487904, -3.714754 40.486013, -3.718133 40.484772, -3.722322 40.477412))
```

And the restriction polygon is this:

```
POLYGON Z ((-3.6832 40.383572 0, -3.681569 40.386187 0, -3.679509 40.389456 0, -3.677793 40.391025 0, -3.67436 40.39377 0, -3.671356 40.395797 0, -3.66921 40.398346 0, -3.66818 40.400111 0, -3.666549 40.403706 0, -3.662172 40.411614 0, -3.659425 40.416776 0, -3.657193 40.417299 0, -3.656335 40.418279 0, -3.658223 40.419848 0, -3.658266 40.421677 0, -3.657794 40.421873 0, -3.655048 40.420762 0, -3.653074 40.420501 0, -3.652129 40.419586 0, -3.650584 40.418802 0, -3.649211 40.418279 0, -3.646808 40.426839 0, -3.639512 40.423376 0, -3.626638 40.415633 0, -3.626809 40.414555 0, -3.624063 40.41364 0, -3.611017 40.418165 0, -3.611274 40.426961 0, -3.611017 40.429942 0, -3.612132 40.434614 0, -3.613935 40.438272 0, -3.616767 40.443825 0, -3.619857 40.44794 0, -3.620458 40.449573 0, -3.62269 40.449638 0, -3.623891 40.449507 0, -3.625522 40.449328 0, -3.62623 40.449344 0, -3.6308 40.449181 0, -3.634126 40.448707 0, -3.636594 40.448266 0, -3.642602 40.449311 0, -3.646207 40.449442 0, -3.648868 40.448985 0, -3.654447 40.446699 0, -3.65788 40.445654 0, -3.660112 40.444935 0, -3.661228 40.444935 0, -3.662343 40.448332 0, -3.663631 40.457149 0, -3.66509 40.460871 0, -3.66818 40.466422 0, -3.672986 40.472364 0, -3.674617 40.476281 0, -3.673673 40.483071 0, -3.676076 40.48405 0, -3.678479 40.483854 0, -3.681741 40.483071 0, -3.684659 40.482353 0, -3.687406 40.483332 0, -3.691182 40.484899 0, -3.694959 40.485682 0, -3.699508 40.483724 0, -3.705001 40.482157 0, -3.709207 40.481243 0, -3.714271 40.480133 0, -3.717532 40.478762 0, -3.721395 40.475955 0, -3.726974 40.473082 0, -3.732982 40.47256 0, -3.737016 40.473147 0, -3.736072 40.468316 0, -3.733497 40.466552 0, -3.735214 40.465312 0, -3.733669 40.463614 0, -3.732209 40.46492 0, -3.730064 40.4595 0, -3.730235 40.456169 0, -3.732295 40.454863 0, -3.736158 40.454602 0, -3.740278 40.454079 0, -3.741737 40.452577 0, -3.742938 40.451532 0, -3.740449 40.447874 0, -3.739248 40.442845 0, -3.737617 40.438272 0, -3.738046 40.435398 0, -3.737874 40.433242 0, -3.737102 40.43089 0, -3.735643 40.428538 0, -3.733068 40.426512 0, -3.72912 40.423899 0, -3.725515 40.422331 0, -3.722425 40.420566 0, -3.721052 40.419717 0, -3.723131 40.416293 0, -3.723475 40.414855 0, -3.723646 40.412699 0, -3.722359 40.410738 0, -3.722101 40.408712 0, -3.722616 40.406294 0, -3.722788 40.402961 0, -3.722187 40.400869 0, -3.721245 40.40065 0, -3.720236 40.40034 0, -3.717552 40.399692 0, -3.715063 40.398777 0, -3.711287 40.396163 0, -3.704506 40.394725 0, -3.703242 40.394555 0, -3.702555 40.394489 0, -3.702426 40.394489 0, -3.70131 40.393247 0, -3.698884 40.38943 0, -3.693477 40.384657 0, -3.6832 40.383572 0))
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what your inputs are. Can you show the isochrone polygon and the restriction polygon together, so we can get a sense of size/shape/relative scale/overlap?

Comment: I was going to add them, but are really huge. I'll edit it